# All Desktops named by EnumDesktops fail to OpenDesktop with error 2 "File not found"

Tags: windows, winapi, desktop

I enumerated the desktops on my system (I'm using SysInternals `Desktops`, so I knew I had extras) using:

```
EnumDesktops(Nothing, AddressOf EnumDesktopsProc, Nothing)
```

with these declarations:

```
Private Declare Auto Function EnumDesktops Lib "User32" (ByVal hWinSta As IntPtr, ByVal edp As EnumDesktopProc, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
Private Declare Auto Function OpenDesktop Lib "User32" (<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> ByVal DesktopName As String, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)>ByVal fInherit As Boolean, ByVal dwDesiredAccess As AccessMask) As DesktopHandle

Private desktopNames As New List(Of String)

Private Delegate Function EnumDesktopProc(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)>ByVal DesktopName As String, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean

Private Function EnumDesktopsProc(
          ByVal DesktopName As String,
          ByVal lParam As IntPtr
        ) As Boolean

    desktopNames.Add(DesktopName)
    Return True
End Function
```

I retrieved:

```
"WinSta0"
"Service-0x0-3e7$"
"Service-0x0-3e4$"
"Service-0x0-3e5$"
"SAWinSta"
"__X78B95_89_IW"
"Service-0x0-119d1e$"
"Service-0x0-4e05f$"
```

And when I attempted to open them with:

```
OpenDesktop(DesktopName, 0, False, AccessMask.DESKTOP_ENUMERATE)
```

(where `AccessMask` is a big `Enum` duplicating the data [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682575.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379607.aspx), and `DesktopHandle` is a `SafeHandle`)

they all return `NULL` (`Nothing`) and `GetLastWin32Error` returns `2 "The system cannot find the file specified."`. Why?

I checked alternate declarations for `OpenDesktop` and different `AccessMask` values with no effect (except when the declaration was actually wrong). I note I could get a different error when adding a "path" to the `DesktopName`, specifically `161 "The specified path is invalid."`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for `EnumDesktops` is at least misleading, if not wrong. Passing `NULL` (`Nothing`) as the first parameter is returning the desktops of the "Session 0" window station. You need to use the result from `GetProcessWindowStation()`. I.e. change the first line above to:

```
Private Declare Auto Function GetProcessWindowStation Lib "User32" () As IntPtr

EnumDesktops(GetProcessWindowStation(), AddressOf EnumDesktopsProc, Nothing)
```

(There is a user comment added to the [`EnumDesktops` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682614.aspx) but I missed it, so I thought others might too.)

Note the documentation for `GetProcessWindowStation` [explicitly says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683225.aspx) it does not need closing, so it doesn't need wrapping in a `SafeHandle`.

Comment: With this EnumDesktops returns "s" and "D" for me. If I try to open them with OpenDesktop it returns a zero handle. Are those names valid desktop names or do I use OpenDesktop wrong?