# How to check if a specific desktop background is visible or if an application runs in fullscreen?

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi, ui-automation, desktop

I'm working on an app that creates a desktop wallpaper diashow (for multi-monitor-setups). I want to skip displays which are not visible, when some other app runs in fullscreen for example.

**EDIT**

I set wallpapers using the `IDesktopWallpaper` interface, which needs a DeviceId.
I managed to get the DeviceNames (like \.\DISPLAY1) and the DeviceIds (like \?\DISPLAY#GSM76FE#5&3b13964d&0&UID4354#{e6f07b5f-ee97-4a90-b076-33f57bf4eaa7}) using `EnumDisplayDevices`.

Now I'm trying to get their corresponding desktops, to get all windows on that desktop, to check if they cover that desktop.

I tried `EnumDesktops`, like stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323174/all-desktops-named-by-enumdesktops-fail-to-opendesktop-with-error-2-file-not-fo), but it only returns the names "s" and "D" for me, and I can't `OpenDesktop` them (it returns a null handle, `GetLastError` returns 2).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to check to see if another program is running full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743956/is-there-a-way-to-check-to-see-if-another-program-is-running-full-screen)

Comment: @Peter Interesting, but no. For example, if the user plays a game on the main monitor in fullscreen, that game will be the window returned by GetForegroundWindow(), but I still need to know if something on the second monitor is in fullscreen.

Comment: There is no way to check for this, unless you are willing to go to length and evaluate any possible combination of windows that will result in a fully obscured desktop. That may sound trivial, just taking the window rectangles and adding them up. But then there are layered windows, either with key color or alpha transparency. And since WinUI seems to love the acrylic brush so much, you'll have to consider another (blurred) transparency mode.

Comment: @IInspectable You're right. Actually, maybe I want to do that. At first I thought about only checking if any window runs in fullscreen, but when I'm checking every window anyways I can also sum their rectangles. I'm not that worried about blurry or glass-style windows, as even then the background may not be that important. I'll have to look into completly transparent windows though. Thank you.

Comment: You can use [`WindowFromPoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-windowfrompoint?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to check if the left-top and right-bottom points belong to a same application. If it is true, the application is in fullscreen mode.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Atm I struggle with getting the desktop of a specific monitor. How does the desktop even work in a multi-monitor setup?

Comment: What's kind of multi-monitor setup? Do you want to detect an application in fullscreen on a single monitor or across multiple monitors?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT On a single monitor. I want to know which monitors are occupied, and which not.

Comment: Same method on per monitor. Get every monitor left-top and right-bottom point and compare the two points to see if they belong to a same application window.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Okay, but I struggle to get the desktop windows, because I can't get a desktopHandle. I do it like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323174/all-desktops-named-by-enumdesktops-fail-to-opendesktop-with-error-2-file-not-fo), but OpenDesktop always returns a null handle :/

Comment: @rit This is an over-simplification, that ignores windows that have called [SetWindowRgn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowrgn), for example.

Comment: @Fox It seems you have multiple desktops associate different monitors. Do you use multiple monitors as independent displays and every independent display has its own desktop?